# Manage website for someone who does not know HTML

Tags: html, server, content-management-system

I am building a couple of websites for a company. The problem is that they do not know any HTML at all, which means that if they would like to change a text or edit something on the webpage, they would need to get a programmer to do it.

Is there any better way for them to edit texts than login into the server and edit the HTML file?
Some sort of an admin page in a sense.

Comment: To generic of a question. Lookup Content Management Systems (CMS).

Comment: Could you give me a link to any good informative websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to perform what you want to do :

- **You can create yourself an admin page**

  It will be longer to code, you will have to take care of every security issues that may exist. But at the end, you will be sure that everybody can change what they want, without editing something they shouldn't.
- **You can use a [Content Management Systems (CMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)**

  A lot of thing will be already coded for what you need. But you're not sure your users can't be lost somewhere they shouldn't be and start editing some essential things.
  Furthermore, some CMS are known [to have security issues](https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-protect-yourself-from-wordpress-security-issues/).

  If you want to use a CMS, you should look at the [list of existing CMSs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP) (*PHP section*), the most popular being [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress), [magento](/questions/tagged/magento), [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) ...

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a CMS like WordPress? Easy to use, easy to develop.